# Multiple use text file

Tags: delphi, append, text-files

I am creating an online store, and want to add a text file while the user is still "shopping", and then use it on a different form as like a form summary.

I am struggling to find a way to rewrite in the text file only when I rerun my code, and not every time I pick a new item.

Any suggestions?

I tried using this:

```
Assignfile(tf,'order.txt')
rewrite(tf)
Writeln(tf,xxx)
End
Else
Assignfile(tf,'order.txt')
Append(tf)
Writeln(tf,xxx)
Closefile(tf)
End
```

Comment: No doubt someone will tell you that your approach is an obsolete way of dealing with text files, and although those routines still work, they would have a point.  It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do.  Is it to open the text file and add a line without rewriting the entire file?  Effectively that happens in the background any way.  One approach would be to use a `TStringList`, which has methods for reading from and writing to a text file.  So you'd load the file into the `TStringList`, add a new line to the list, then write it back to the file.

Comment: Why would an online store be made in Delphi? Isn't this a web application?

Comment: You don't exchange data between forms (web pages) via a text file. The data should be kept in a database.

Comment: I have to use delphi because that is the programming language we are using at our school and our practical assessment for the year is to make an online store "website"

Comment: What I want to do is to use one text file that will temporarily store all the items the user has selected everytime they add an item to their cart and I then want to use that info in a different form where I can extract all that is stored in the textile and once I stop running the program, the data in the textile is deleted or deleted whenever I run the code again

Comment: Or any suggestions of what I can use to execute such other than using a text file?

Comment: If you want to stick with the approach you've tried, at the very least show more of your code.  You have an `else` in there, but no `if then`, so we can't even see where the problem might be.  Also, I don't understand what you mean by "rewrite in the text file only when I rerun my code, and not every time I pick a new item."  You've indicated in a comment that you want to do something "everytime they add an item to their cart".  Those two statements appear to me to contradict each other.  I've not used databases, so I can't help you with that.